# Wifi router 300mbps vs real speed?

Tags: wireless-networking, speed, isp

I have this router TP-LINK TL-WR841N (300 mbps 2.4Ghz).
My ISP provided me 30mbps/4mbps and on Wifi I always got about the same.

BUT, today, my ISP has changed and provides me 70mbps/10mbps.
With an Ethernet cable, I get about 65mbps/9mbps so... perfect.

BUT, on Wifi, I can't reach more than about 32mbps in download ! Upload is perfect (~9mbps)

Am I wrong or a 300mbps Wifi router should be enough for my 70mbps ISP ? or I'm totally wrong ?

I really hope someone will help me to understand this, thank you =)

Comment: You're totally wrong. Welcome to the sucky world of 2.4GHz. How is the router configured? What channel is it on? What channel width? What other networks are in range of your devices?

Comment: Hello =)
The Wifi router is set to AP mode, DHCP off. It's linked to the main modem via Ethernet cable. Everything is OK for this as it never changed =).

My Wifi router is set on channel 6 and widht is set on auto (20/40 mhz).
There are some other networks on 1, 6, 11, 9 channels.

Comment: Weird, I made a new test and now I get 42mbps down... but still not 65 ^^

Comment: The problem is the network on channel 9, as it partially overlaps yours. You should try to convince that other network, if you can, to switch to 1, 6, or 11. Otherwise, switch to 1 and 20MHz yourself.

Comment: Ok thank you I'll try this and let you know.
Btw, is that possible it's also related to sth like this sentence I found on another website: "Don't forget that megabits and Megabytes aren't the same units, in fact 300 mbps = only 37.5mb/s" ???

Answer (score 1):

Unlike wired connections, which are stable and reliable, wireless connection on the other hand, as the medium is open **and shared**, they are not. 
On wireless connections speeds vary widely depending on various conditions, such as number of overlapping channels (number of AP's and STA near you competing for signal on the same channel), signal attenuation (loss of signal strength because of distance or when it has to go through walls or other objects), and the list goes on and on.
For you to achieve the maximum advertised throughput, the PRx has to be equal or higher than a certain power, called the Srx (Sensivity), sometimes the manufacturer advertises this value, other times it does not.

Are you near your router while you're testing, or are you in another room? How many walls are between your router and the STA (Laptop/Desktop) you're testing?

If you go to Control Panel/Network and Internet/Network Connections, and double click your wireless adapter, what's the advertised speed and signal quality?

How many AP's do you have near you? Can you download Inssider --> http://www.techspot.com/downloads/5936-inssider.html and run it to check how many overlapping networks are there?

Regards.

Comment: Hello and thank you for yout answer =)

Yes I'm near my Wifi router, it's not far from my desk, on the same room. To be more accurate, I get -39db with Inssider.
Then signal quality is Excellent and advertised speed is 144mbps.

I also use a USB Wifi adapter that works great and it's a 300mbps device.

And here is a screenshot of what Inssider shows me http://hpics.li/9718544

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Hello. Is your SSID pikachu? If so, the advertised max rate is 54 Mb/s. That's the reason you're only getting 30 something Mb/s. Have you checked the configuration page of your router? Have you chosen N only (Wireless Mode) just to test? It's on this page of your router -- http://bit.ly/1JiIYjY

Comment: Hello yes it's Pikachu.
That's weird, because when I test with another laptop near the router, with 300mbps on speed on Inssider, I also get about 30mbps, sometimes more ~35mbps.

I'll try N only then =)

Comment: Try it and check first on Inssider if the Max Rate goes up.

Comment: Actually I have another problem, my Wireless router is set on AP mode and I can't find his IP anymore so I can't go into the settings...
I'll first have to figure this out lol

Comment: You can just reset it if you don't find the IP address, according to the manual (http://bit.ly/1TTSd5f): _Use the WPS/RESET button: With the Router powered on, press and hold the
WPS/RESET button (more than 5 seconds) until the SYS LED becomes quick-flash from
slow-flash. Then release the button and wait the Router to reboot to its factory default
settings_

Comment: Everybody in the house is using Internet at the moment so I can't turn the router off.
Btw the Wifi router IP was 192.168.1.70 before I changed my ISP (and then changed modem too). But I didn't change the Wifi router IP so I dont understand why I can't reach it anymore with 192.168.1.70. Especially because I set it manually, it shoudn't change...
Any idea ? =)

Comment: But what's the IP address of the computer you're trying to connect the router with? Is it in the same network (192.168.1.1-192.168.1.254)?

Comment: No I think the problem is that the new modem has another IP "structure" It's not 192.168.1.x but 192.168.178.x

Comment: So they're in different networks. If the management ip address is 192.168.178.x/24, it means that your ip address should be 192.168.178.y/24 in order for you to be able to access it. Do you know how to set the IP address manually?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the y/24 or x/24 =(

Comment: You said that the management IP address is on the 192.168.178.0/24 network, which means that in order for one host (computer, whatever) to connect to the management interface, you need to be in the same network. In order to accomplish that, you need to manually set the IP address of the host which is going to connect to the router to somehting like 192.168.178.120 (for example, it can be any value from 1-254 which is not being used). For manually configuring the IP address of the host, go to Control Panel/Network and Internet/Network Connections, right click proprieties and then change it.

Comment: Thank you !!! I managed to change my Wifi router IP adresse to match with my new modem =)

But unfortunately I can't choose Wifi N only. There's only mixed or b+g.
But I switched to channel 1 and it seems to be better (~43mbps now)

So as I understand and as you said, my "problem" is only due to interference ? It has nothing to do with this "Don't forget that megabits and Megabytes aren't the same units, in fact 300 mbps = only 37.5mb/s"  ???

Comment: Have you upgraded your Router firmware (http://bit.ly/1J56hk2)? What about Inssider Max Rate after the change?

Comment: Yes my Tp link router firmware is updated =)
And no, same Max Rate but even with another laptop with Max Rate at 300 in Inssider, I get the same speed ...

Comment: You do have some overlapping networks, but near the router you should achieve a little more. Anyway, just check if you don't have any limitations regarding bandwidth, as there is bandwidth control in your router, so check if it's disabled (http://bit.ly/1KwvYI9). I would suggest an factory reset, but you say there is a lot of hosts connected.